# Use input field value from standard controller with a extension property

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to enter in the fields the new variables of the class "NewAddrees" extension
I know my syntax is wrong but I do not know how to solve it

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="NewAddress">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Nombre de la cuenta: {!Account.Name}">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Direccion de Facturacion" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" tabOrderHint="1"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingCity}" tabOrderHint="2"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingState}" tabOrderHint="3"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}" tabOrderHint="4"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>


     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Direccion de Envio" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingStreet}" tabOrderHint="1"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingCity}" tabOrderHint="2"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingState}" tabOrderHint="3"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingPostalCode}" tabOrderHint="4"/>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>



    <apex:pageBlockSection title="new Address" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalStreet}" tabOrderHint="1"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalCity}" tabOrderHint="2"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalState}" tabOrderHint="3"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalPostalCode}" tabOrderHint="4"/>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>

  </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>




 public class NewAddress {
        private final Account account;

        public NewAddress(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            account = (account)controller.getRecord();
        }

        public String FiscalStreet { get; set; }
        public String FiscalCity { get; set; }
        public String FiscalState{ get; set; }
        public String FiscalPostalCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly refer the attributes of your `NewAddress` class without appending Account to it. Only change would be that you cannot make use of `<apex:inputField>` as the variables declared in your extension class are not an sObject's field, instead you can use `<apex:inputText>` to capture input from users.

This is how it should be refered

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="new Address" columns="1">
    <apex:inputText value="{!FiscalStreet}" tabindex="1"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!FiscalCity}" tabindex="2"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!FiscalState}" tabindex="3"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!FiscalPostalCode}" tabindex="4"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

You can get help on this topic at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) and [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hsE6AAI) link

Comment: error console " Error: Atributo taborderhint no compatible en <apex:inputText>" with your code :(

Comment: You can use `tabindex` instead of `taborderhint` for `inputText` as there is no attribute called as `taborderhint` for `inputText`. Updated the answer.

Comment: thank you but now all property are unknow error console example... " Error: Property 'AccountStandardController.FiscalStreet' unknow"

Comment: I can solve, this was error syntax.

Comment: That's great !!

Comment: i have last question,which you think is the best way to pass the data from the fields of this example to a map with marks
Google maps, leaftlet. js?or other ?

Comment: You can refer [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/account-geolocation-app/lc-app-06) and [this](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/how-to-use-leaflet-map-in-salesforce/) link for the above question. But I would recommend you to post a separate question for this so that the wider community can have a look at your requirement and can help you better.

Comment: Hi Vijay, do you can help please with a new problem with this code please https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252701/how-can-i-convert-this-apex-page-to-lighting-component