# How can I convert my apex page to lighting component?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I want to put my apex page in the in this view,
below the map
[image: the view]

I try to customize this example
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/es-MX/content/learn/projects/account-geolocation-app/lc-app-04

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="NewAddress">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Nombre de la cuenta: {!Account.Name}">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Direccion de Facturacion" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" tabOrderHint="1"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingCity}" tabOrderHint="2"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingState}" tabOrderHint="3"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}" tabOrderHint="4"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>


     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Direccion de Envio" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingStreet}" tabOrderHint="1"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingCity}" tabOrderHint="2"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingState}" tabOrderHint="3"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingPostalCode}" tabOrderHint="4"/>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>



    <apex:pageBlockSection title="new Address" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalStreet}" tabOrderHint="1"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalCity}" tabOrderHint="2"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalState}" tabOrderHint="3"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalPostalCode}" tabOrderHint="4"/>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>

  </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
 public class NewAddress {
        private final Account account;

        public NewAddress(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            account = (account)controller.getRecord();
        }

        public String FiscalStreet { get; set; }
        public String FiscalCity { get; set; }
        public String FiscalState{ get; set; }
        public String FiscalPostalCode { get; set; }
    }
```

AccountLocator.cmp

```
 <aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
        <div>
            <div>
                <c:AccountMap />
            </div>
            <div>
                <c:AccountList />
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:component>
```

AccountLocatorapp

```
<aura:application >
    <c:AccountLocator/>
</aura:application>
```

AccountListen.cmp

```
<aura:component>
     <aura:registerEvent name="accountSelected" type="c:AccountSelected"/>
     <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account"/>
     <li><a onclick="{!c.accountSelected}">{!v.account.Name}</a></li> </aura:component>
```

AccountListItemController.js

```
 ({
            accountSelected : function(component) {
                var event = $A.get("e.c:AccountSelected");
                event.setParams({"account": component.get("v.account")});
                event.fire();
            }
        })

AccountListController.cmp


({
        doInit : function(component, event) {
            var action = component.get("c.findAll");
            action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
                component.set("v.accounts", a.getReturnValue());
                window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function() {
                    var event = $A.get("e.c:AccountsLoaded");
                    event.setParams({"accounts": a.getReturnValue()});
                    event.fire();
                }), 500);
            });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    })


AccountList.cmp

<aura:component controller="AccountController">
    <aura:registerEvent name="accountsLoaded" type="c:AccountsLoaded"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <ul>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
        <c:AccountListItem account="{!account}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
</aura:component>
```

AccountSelected.evt

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="account" Type="Account"/>
</aura:event>
```

Comment: Where is the other components markup

Comment: Ready Eric, i add the other components, it is the same example that link https://trailhead.salesforce.com/es-MX/content/learn/projects/account-geolocation-app/lc-app-04  but i want customize